# Error Installing tesseract-ocr Python 3.5 win 10

Tags: python

I have some problems with python . I'm trying to install python using pip :

-m pip install tesseract-ocr

for python 3.5 and here is the error I get:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\include -IC:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /EHsc /Tptesseract_ocr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\tesseract_ocr.obj
tesseract_ocr.cpp
tesseract_ocr.cpp(517): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'leptonica/allheaders.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

How can I fix this? Tks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can [download wrapper](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/AddOns#tesseract-wrappers) and install it, also [this](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) package. But you should have `tesseract-ocr` installed on your PC